# Force Cucumber to execute the scenarios in a particular order

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, scenarios, cucumber-java

I have a feature file with 5 scenarios :

```
@Scenario_1
@labelA
Given....

@Scenario_2
@labelB
Given....

@Scenario_3
@labelA
Given....

@Scenario_4
@labelA
Given...

@Scenario_5
@labelB
Given...
```

On my system, it executes in the same order in which it is present on the FF - 1,2,3,4,5. However, on a VM, it executes in any random order, like 4,1,5,3,2.

I need 1 to be compulsorily executed before 2, and 2 to be compulsorily executed before 3 and so on. Is there a way to force Cucumber to run the scenarios in the order in which they are present in the feature file ?

Comment: If your scenarios are order dependent, you don't have seperate scenarios. You have one big ol' scenario.

Comment: I agree with @jeffPrice on that. You are on a bad road. Each test should be independent. What happens if the first scenario fails? If you have ORM, then inject the data needed for each scenario, and clean up in the before hooks (or after, but I prefer before).

Comment: In a perfect world, scenarios would be independent and we would all use Grid.  But I don't live in that world.  Something is wrong because cucumber is supposed to run scenarios in the "Order of scenarios within the feature file". I run cucumber on a VM all the time and I don't see this behavior.  Please tell us more.

Comment: as far as i know cucumber doesnt guarante the order of the scenarios, so you shouldn't depend on it. If you need a specific state you should genereate it in a Given step. If you cant, what is the harm in writing everything in one scenario? i depends on each other anyway

Answer (score -3):

to do this one way is : to order the features at the lauching of the cucumber executable :

i.e.

./cucumber.sh myfeatures\second\1.feature features\first\2.feature features

where will be executed in order:

1. myfeatures\second\1.feature, then
2. features\first\2.feature, then
3. features.